# How to compute tf-idf for a dataframe of multiple responses?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, tf-idf

I have a dataframe called `Q1Dummy` consisting of 2 columns: `resp_id` (respondent ID) and `Q1` (responses they made in a string format).

It looks like this:

```
resp_id    Q1
1          Ik vind het niet helemaal netjes om je sociale huurwoning te verhuren, aangezien je dan mensen passeert die al lang op de wachtrij staan of er meer recht op hebben.
2          Ja dat vind ik heel goed omdat mensen die al heel lang op zoek zijn ook een huisje kunnen krijgen.
3          Ik vind het iets begrijpelijks. Als je in de sociale huur zit, geeft het al aan dat je een klein inkomen hebt. Het is fijn om de woning dan achter de hand te hebben als extra inkomen en uitvalsbasis in een stad als Amsterdam. Ook de huur illegaal met iemand delen, waardoor je beide geld bespaard, is een logisch gevolg van de krapte op de huizenmarkt. Ondanks dat het iets illegaals is kan ik er dus begrip voor opbrengen.
...        ...
n          Dat kan echt niet. Je maakt winst op een woning waar subsidie opzit. Daar is de woning niet voor bedoeld.
```

Now, for text mining purposes I would like to unnest the responses in ngrams (of 3), as I did below:

```
tokensQ1Dummy <- Q1Dummy %>%
    unnest_tokens(words, Q1, token = "ngrams", n = 3, n_min = 1) %>%
    count(words, sort = TRUE)
```

The next step is calculating tf-idf. There are several functions for this, but the problem is that when creating the `tokensQ1Dummy` dataframe above the respondent IDs are lost. So my question is how to compute the tf-idf for the created tokens from this point on.

Thanks!

Comment: What about the `bind_tf_idf()` function of the `tidytext` package? Looks simple enough [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tf_idf.html).

Comment: Hi @LAP, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the `bind_tf_idf()`-function requires some sort of ID argument, which was lost by creating the tokens (because some tokens appear in multiple responses).

Comment: tfidf should be calculated when the document ids are still there, otherwise they can't be calculated, because you need to know in how many documents the terms appear. Why don't you group by resp_id? Then you can use `bind_tf_idf()` without any issue.

Comment: Hi @phiver, thanks for your answer. The problem with grouping by resp_id is that than some tokens will appear multiple times, because multiple respondents use them. Is there a way to keep the IDs but not have the tokens appear multiple times?

Comment: That is the whole point of tfidf. The same token can be in multiple documents and in each document it will have a different tfidf weight. If, for example, you remove resp_id and just add 1 documentid for everything the tfidf will be 0 for all terms. I have the feeling you are not looking for a tf-idf, but just for a proportion of the features either based on the total number of features or the feature counts of the highest feature count in the dataset.